# Why is my function running on all created elements?

Tags: javascript

I have written a basic function (celebrate) that runs onmouseenter a link on my page.

It creates a p element and then calls a function (move) which moves the element from the right to the left of the page.

I want this move function to run even if you mouseleave the element.

Unfortunately, not only does the moving text dissappear when you mouseout, but all the links move at the same rate. If an element starts moving and you mouseover to create a new moving element, it moves both the moving elements back to the right hand side and moves them in line with each other.

I know I'm doing something wrong with the code but I don't know what :)

```
function celebrate(link) {
    let celebration = document.createElement("p");
    let celebrationtext = document.createTextNode(link.text);
    celebration.appendChild(celebrationtext);
    document.body.appendChild(celebration);
    celebration.className = 'moving';
    celebration.style.top = link.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    move(celebration, 1100);
}

function move(object, X){
    let thisobject = object;
    console.log(thisobject);
    if ( object != null ) {
        intX=X-3;
        thisobject.style.left = (intX).toString() + 'px';
    } //if
    if ( X > 0 ) { 
        setTimeout(function(){move(thisobject,intX)},20); 
    } else {
        thisobject.remove();
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have created a JSfiddle using the chapter titles of Eloquent Javascript

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/63njmxrt/1/)

Comment: `var intX=X-3;` should fix the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `setTimeout` function as below.

```
setTimeout(move, 20, thisobject, intX);
```

Above is the proper way to pass parameters with `setTimeout`.

It is like setTimeout(function, timeout, param1, param2,..)

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/evg7npbL/

Answer (score 2):

That is because your `intX` is a global and all `move(thisobject,intX)` use it.

If you declare inside the `move` function it gets fixed.

```
let thisobject = object,
    intX;
```

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/63njmxrt/6/

---

Or you could remove the `intX` completely and just decrease the `X` when passing it as a parameter

```
function move(object, X) {
  let thisobject = object;

  if (object != null) {
    thisobject.style.left = (X).toString() + 'px';
  } //if
  if (X > 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      move(thisobject, X-3)
    }, 20);
  } else {
    thisobject.remove();
  }
  return true;
}
```